# Aurelia-dialog using attach-focus on custom element

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm trying to pass `attach-focus="true"` to one of the inner elements of a custom element so that the correct element will receive the focus when aurelia-dialog opens.

**Custom element: enum-list.html**

```
<template>
  <label class="control-label">${label} DEBUG: ${attach-focus}</label>
  <select class="form-control" value.bind="value" attach-focus.bind="attach-focus">
    <option if.bind="data" repeat.for="code of data | keys" value="${code}">${data[code]}</option>
  </select>
</template>
```

**Custom element: enum-list.js**

```
import { bindable, bindingMode } from 'aurelia-framework';
export class EnumListCustomElement {
  @bindable label;
  @bindable data;
  @bindable attach-focus; // <-- Maybe the source of the error?
  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) value;
}
```

**Dialog template: edit-locale.html:**

```
<template>
  <ai-dialog>
    <ai-dialog-header class="modal-header modal-header-success">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Locale</h4>
    </ai-dialog-header>
    <ai-dialog-body>
      <form>
        <enum-list attach-focus="true" label="Language" data.bind="core.enums.SystemLanguage" value.bind="sch_lang"></enum-list>
        <enum-list label="Currency" data.bind="core.enums.CurrencyCode" value.bind="sch_currency"></enum-list>
      </form>
    </ai-dialog-body>
    <ai-dialog-footer>
      <button type="button" click.trigger="dialogController.cancel()">Cancel</button>
      <button type="button" click.delegate="dialogController.ok()">Save</button>
    </ai-dialog-footer>
  </ai-dialog>
</template>
```

**Instantiation (from my VM js):**

```
this.dialogService.open({ viewModel: EditLocale, model: this.record, lock: true }).then(response => {
```

The modal dialog loads fine if I remove the dashes from attach-focus in `edit-locale.js` and inside the custom element.  But with the dash, I'm getting an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`.  I think the dash is interfering but I don't know how to fix it.

My preference is to fix it so that the instantiation of the custom control has the standard parameter `attach-focus="true"` (with the dash) so that it's consistent with normal elements like INPUT and SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the source of the error, you can't have a `property-name` containing a dash. Because it reads as `property - name`.

There is a convention in aurelia ([link to docs](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-custom-elements/1), search for dash-case) to map attributes and elements name from dash notation to camelCase notation, so if in your model you will name your bindable property as `@bindable attachFocus` - you will be able to use it in you views as  attach-focus.bind="true".

Also make sure that you `<require>` your custom elements/attributes in your views or make them globally available when configuring aurelia.